# Error while retriving the last row of a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I was trying to take the last row from my customer table,While executing the following Query:

```
 mystring = " mystring = "SELECT TOP 1 customer_id FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id DESC""
 openconnection()
 cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(mystring, myconnection)
 MsgBox(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
 closeconnection()
```

An error message is shown as follows:

**"check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax 
to use near '1 customer_id FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id DESC' at line 1"**

Can anyone suggest me that why this error occur, what are the changes i need to do in my query 
to get the expected result.

Comment: i thing the tag was wrongly suggested change it as MySql

Comment: @SujithKarivelil are you disputing or agreeing with my tag change, and if you're disagreeing, why?

Comment: `TOP 1` is SQL Server syntax.  Use `limit` instead.

Comment: Ad @lekha, is `mystring = " mystring = "SELECT...` a typo? I can change it if so, or you can, I just didn't want to change something that was actually right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the "few" (I expect a bit of backlash on that one) differences between T-SQL and MySQL. While in TSQL, you'd be spot on by calling `SELECT TOP n ...`, in MySQL you should use the [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) keyword to specify that you want only `n` number of rows.

In your specific case, you'd want to call a statement similar to this:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customer
ORDER BY customer_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

---

**This isn't really related to your question**, but just since I gather you haven't used `LIMIT` before, I'll throw in a bit of extra credit. `LIMIT` is also how you write paging expressions in MySQL, so if you ever find yourself needing to, say, display only pages of ten, you could write a query such as this:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customer
ORDER BY customer_id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

then for the second page,

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM customer
ORDER BY customer_id DESC
LIMIT 10, 10
```

Again, not related to your question, everything above the line should do that, but I thought it might be useful to have as knowledge in the back of your mind.

Comment: what i need to do if where condition is needed to apply with this query? can i select columns other than primary key through this query?

Comment: @SujithKarivelil definitely. Just add in a `WHERE [column] = "value"` between the `FROM` and `ORDER BY` clauses for filtering, and you can select whatever columns you choose by specifying them in the `SELECT`, or just listing `SELECT * FROM...`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use LIMIT in mysql instead of `TOP` like

```
SELECT customer_id FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

```
mystring = " mystring = "SELECT TOP 1 customer_id FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id DESC""
```

I am using MAX customer_id because from your code you are ordering by customer_id

**2.**

```
mystring = " mystring = "SELECT TOP 1 customer_id FROM customer ORDER BY customer_id DESC""
```

I am not able to understand mystring is used twice without any concatination so beliving it a typo i am changing it to

```
mystring = "SELECT MAX(customer_id) FROM customer;"
openconnection()
cmd = New Odbc.OdbcCommand(mystring, myconnection)
MsgBox(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
closeconnection()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Customer_id from Customer Order By Customer_id DESC Limit 0 , 1 ;
```

and if you want only 2nd last customer id then use

```
Select * from CustomerB Order By CustomerID DESC Limit 1 , 1 ;
```

for last 3rd position value

```
Select * from CustomerB Order By CustomerID DESC Limit 2 , 1 ;
```